# Error Generating JavaDoc on Mac Android Studio

Tags: java, android, macos

I am running Android Studio 1.3.2 on a Macbook with Yosemite. When I try to generate Javadoc for my project I get a lot of errors starting with the few lines below. I tried adding the command line arguments: -bootclasspath /Users/marcusreynolds/android-sdks/platforms/android-22 but this didn't help. I have the same version of Android Studio running on Windows 7 and the Javadoc generation works fine. Any idea of what the problem is? Thanks!

/Users/marcusreynolds/android-sdks/sources/android-22/java/lang/Class.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
import dalvik.system.VMStack;

```
                ^
```

symbol:   class VMStack
  location: package dalvik.system

/Users/marcusreynolds/android-sdks/sources/android-22/java/lang/Class.java:59: error: package libcore.reflect does not exist
import libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess;

```
                  ^
```

/Users/marcusreynolds/android-sdks/sources/android-22/java/lang/Class.java:60: error: package libcore.reflect does not exist
import libcore.reflect.GenericSignatureParser;

```
                  ^
```

/Users/marcusreynolds/android-sdks/sources/android-22/java/lang/Class.java:61: error: package libcore.reflect does not exist
import libcore.reflect.InternalNames;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's look like you have problem with Android sdk. Do you sure that you install Android Studio and android-sdk correctly and do you use Mac version of both? If yes, try to reinstall Android Studio and android-sdk again, may be it's help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Viacheslav, I forgot that I had downgraded Android Studio a few weeks ago and that was the root of the problem I think. After un-installing the Android-22 SDK and Re-installing it again the problem went away and Javadoc is working fine now. :-)